# Xcode - How to share the app in development with clients?

Tags: iphone, xcode, client

I'm developing an iphone app for a client. How can he see the work-in-progress of the app on his iphone and other different iphones?

Answer (score 3):

Look up adhoc distribution in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Graham, thank you! I have the Ad_Hoc_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision.... but how do I create the application file in xcode?

Comment: Build the app and find the .app file in the `build` directory within your project directory.