# How to share an Android app in development with a remote user

Tags: android

I would like to know what options are available and what recommendations are for sharing an Android app that is in development. I basically have the same question that can be found here, but for Android rather than iPhone [Xcode - How to share the app in development with clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764255/xcode-how-to-share-the-app-in-development-with-clients)

I have a friend that I would like to show an app that I just developed. My friend is a non-developer, so the easiest method to do this would be great. I'm new to Android development, so I would like to know what suggestions some of you have who are more versed on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send him your apk file by mail.The OS will install it automatically.
(Your friend's phone must accept applications from unknown sources)

Comment: Dang it! It's that easy?? Just quick question . . . does the receiving phone need to be in Debugging mode? So, they would just need to transfer the file into their phone? Would it work if I sent a link to the .apk hosted on a website and they browsed to it with their phone? Would it automatically install? Thanks so much!!

Comment: No, the receiving phone don't need to be in Debugging mode, this mode is used for the phone to be viewable by adb.
And yes a link to the apk file work too!
think of the apk file like an simple exe file for Windows!nothing to deal with an iOS app

Comment: This doesn't work in 2023.
I'd like to see a modern answer.

Comment: Your comment on a 11 year old post is irrelevant...